Assigning a color to each dot of a dataset using plt.errorbar
I want to plot a dataset with errobars, with each dot in a different color.
I tried the following (which works if i use plt.scatter)
colors = np.array(['blue','red','orange','orange','green','green'])

plt.figure()
plt.errorbar(position,cd,yerr=error,c=colors)
plt.show()

But this code gives me the error : "ValueError: array(['blue', 'red', 'orange', 'orange', 'green', 'green'], dtype='<U6') is not a valid value for color"
Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this issue?

If you want to only give different-different color to the errorbar lines  then instead of using the color(c) argument use the ecolor argument

ecolorcolor, default: None

The color of the errorbar lines. If None, use the color of the line connecting the markers.


colors = np.array(['blue', 'red', 'orange', 'orange', 'green', 'green'])
plt.figure()
plt.errorbar(position, cd, yerr=error, ecolor=colors)
plt.show()


[![enter image description here][2]][2]

IF you want to also change the color of point and the errorlines, then you can use this code

plt.figure()
for i in range(len(position)):
    plt.errorbar(position[i], cd[i], yerr=error[i], ecolor=colors[i], fmt="o", capsize=5)
plt.show()



Thank you for your answer! Using ecolor gives me the same error message unfortunately..

@Baptiste What code you are running it is not giving me any error, I am running same code

I am running Python 3.9.7 can you show me the code that works for you?

@Baptiste I am running this code, see the edit

indeed, it works, but it doesnt work when i add a "capsize" parameter. Thanks for your help. Do you have an idea to do the same for the dots? As i also want them to be shown in the same colour as the ones of the errorbars?

@Baptiste You have not points on the figure, I mean you have not set the type of point you want so for now you will not see any dot in the graph

I want to see the points, so I add fmt = 'o' in my plt.errorbar command. Now I see the dots, but they are not in the same colour as the error bars

@Baptiste so you don't want this straight line in graph right?

No i don't want the line. I tried to do markerfacecolor=colors such as you did with ecolor, but it doesnt work

@Baptiste Check the updated code

Your code indeed works. I added color=colours[i] in order to have the bars and the dots in the same colour. Thanks a lot for your help!!
